The existence of patterns with unique pairwise distances
You've got an infinite grid, and $n$ pieces. You must place them in such a way that the (taxicab) distance between each pair is unique, and there's one pair with distance 1, one pair with distance 2, and so on until one pair with distance ${n \choose 2}$. For what values of $n$ is such a placement possible?
I've done a partial proof here that shows that no solutions are possible except when either $n$ or $n-2$ are square. However, this does not show that solutions exist for these values. Are there better restrictions on values of n? Or must solutions always exist for these values?
I've been able to find solutions for 2, 3, 4, 6 and 9 points with a program, but it's too slow to go further.

Can you include the code? There might be folks here that can speed it up and find additional values of $n$. Once you have enough data points then visiting OEIS and adding those additional terms could narrow this down to a reasonable conjecture if it isn't solely the square property you described.

The pieces are point-size and are placed at the grid vertices, right?

@AlexRavsky yes that is correct.

A one-dimensional counterpart of the question concerns perfect Golomb rulers. But they fail to exist when $n\ge 5$.

@SidharthGhoshal The code I used, while not very readable, can be found here: https://pastebin.com/j1Y16gV0

loosely related to the graceful tree conjecture http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/op/graceful_tree_conjecture
